# how to import a font which is not present in system using css

Tags: css, web

i was tried a lot with this code..

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    src: url('../font/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('../font/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: What about googleapi? You can use it

Comment: have you checked network panel in console?? whether font request is initialized or not?

Comment: What's the problem when you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fonts provided by Google. Just paste the link in the 
`<head>`
section.

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then integrate the font in your CSS

`font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;`

if the font `Alegreya Sans SC` is not loaded then `sans-serif` is applied.